# conditional probabilities with Not

Tags: probability

Example: find P(A|B), when
P(B|A) = 0.8,
P(B|~A) = 0.3,
P(A) = 0.2

What can i do with P(B|~A), and does it look any different in the Venn diagram than P(~A)? I'm super confused.

Comment: Do you know the equation for calculating conditional probabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow these steps:

(1) From $P(A)$ and $P(B|A)$, find $P(B\cap A)$.

(2) From $P(A)$ find $P(\sim A)$ and then from $P(B|\sim A)$, find $P(B \cap \sim A)$

(3) Using (1) and (2), find $P(B)$.

(4) Find $P(A | B)$